# Removing non-adjacent duplicates comparing all fields

Tags: abap

What is the most (time) efficient way of removing all exact duplicates from an unsorted standard internal table (non-deep structure, arbitrarily large)?

All I can think of is simply sorting the entire thing by all of its fields before running `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM itab COMPARING ALL FIELDS`. Is there a faster or preferred alternative? Will this cause problems if the structure mixes alphanumeric fields with numerics?

To provide context, I'm trying to improve performance on some horrible select logic in legacy programs. Most of these run full table scans on 5-10 joined tables, some of them self-joining. I'm left with hundreds of thousands of rows in memory and I'm fairly sure a large portion of them are just duplicates. However, changing the actual selects is too complex and would require */ex[tp]ensive/* retesting. Just removing duplicates would likely cut runtime in half but I want to make sure that the deduplication doesn't add too much overhead itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would investigate two methods:

- Store the original index in an auxiliary field, `SORT BY` the fields you want to compare (possibly using `STABLE`), `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES`, then re-`SORT BY` the stored index.
- Using a `HASHED TABLE` for the fields you want to compare, `LOOP` through the data table. Use `READ TABLE .. TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS` on the hashed table to find out whether the value already existed and if so, remove it - otherwise add the values to the hashed table.

I'm not sure about the performance, but I would recommend to use `SAT` on a plausible data set for both methods and compare the results.

Comment: Wouldn't a hashed table be suboptimal both in runtime, index size and code complexity when comparing a large number (or in this case all) fields?

Comment: You won't know it unless you measure it. :-) If you have to compare all fields, that might be the case.

Comment: Hah, a good point indeed. If I were handling more critical reports I'd definitely budget for more in-depth analysis. However, after cutting out the dreaded `FOR ALL ENTRIES` statements from these selects I've already cut runtime by 95%. I'll definitely check your suggestions out so the reports are fully optimised for our larger live environments though. (And thanks as always for sharing your experience. ^^)

Comment: The performance of the hash table might surprise you. Any approach with a SORT will be O(N log N) or worse the hash table when used correctly will give you O(N). So, with large data sets the hash table will win out.

Comment: @GertBeukema On the other hand, one might argue that the interpreted logic to fill the hashed table is probably slower than the built-in native sorting and deduplication. Only one way to find out: Measure. If there's one thing I've learned the hard way, it's never to assume anything when it comes to performance.

Comment: It's because I'd have to build the hash on all fields that I asked this question to see what alternatives there were that I might have missed. As you say I'd have to test exhaustively to say for sure but I've got some solid alternatives now.